# CakePHP input stopped working

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm completely new with cake, so I have no clue what happened.

this code works :

```
echo $this->Form->input('phone',
        array(
            'required' => false,
            'div' => 'form-group',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'label' => array(
                'class' => 'control-label',
                'text' => __d('admin', 'Tel. numeris')
            ),
            'placeholder' => __d('admin', 'Tel. numeris'),
            'error' => array(
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'alert alert-danger'
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

this one doesn't :

```
echo $this->Form->input('email',
        array(
            'required' => false,
            'div' => 'form-group',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'label' => array(
                'class' => 'control-label',
                'text' => __d('admin', 'El.paštas')
            ),
            'placeholder' => __d('admin', 'El.paštas'),
            'error' => array(
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'alert alert-danger'
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

and for example if I change email to, lets say, emailas, it works too(but then it doesnt do anything) :

```
echo $this->Form->input('emailas',
        array(
            'required' => false,
            'div' => 'form-group',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'label' => array(
                'class' => 'control-label',
                'text' => __d('admin', 'El.paštas')
            ),
            'placeholder' => __d('admin', 'El.paštas'),
            'error' => array(
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'alert alert-danger'
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

could someone please help me or at least tell me where to look? The input stopped working out of the blue, so maybe theres a possibility to somehow restart whole plugin? THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

P.S.
This is how the input field looks atm vs how it should look like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzD2H.jpg

Comment: Have you noticed the one that doesn't work is the one that has foreign characters, have you tried removing these and see if it then works, if thats the case it clearly doesn't support foreign characters to be used.

Comment: @DannyBroadbent no, thats not the case. it does say the text, but it doesnt display the input field. instead it only says email. here's how it looks : http://imgur.com/bBrkgxM

Comment: In the class for building the schema have you ensured ->addField('email', ['type' => 'string']) is present

Comment: try this => echo $this->Form->input('email',
        array(
            'required' => false, 'type'=>'email',
            'div' => 'form-group',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'label' => array(
                'class' => 'control-label',
                'text' => __d('admin', 'El.paštas')
            ),
            'placeholder' => __d('admin', 'El.paštas'),
            'error' => array(
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'alert alert-danger'
                )
            )
        )
    );

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('email',
        array(
            'required' => false,
            'div' => 'form-group',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'type' => 'email',
            'label' => array(
                'class' => 'control-label',
                'text' => __d('admin', 'El.paštas')
            ),
            'placeholder' => __d('admin', 'El.paštas'),
            'error' => array(
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'alert alert-danger'
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

And make sure you have email field in database and nowhere is overriding email field (in controller / model)